# PHP cUrl fetch website content for offline usage

Tags: php, curl, hyperlink, fetch, offline

Is it possible to save all website content for offline usage via curl ?

Basically fetch all HTML, css, js, pictures, audio, flash etc...

```
<?php    
$curl = curl_init();    
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'',
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://edition.cnn.com/'
));    
$resp = curl_exec($curl);   
echo $resp;    
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

I'm getting website content back but **how do I SAVE** it as separate files ?

Thanks !

Comment: to download everything, it'd probably easier to spawn a shell running wget

Comment: I like the sound of wget - I am looking at php because I think I can get the nodes within the html easily...I am trying to get the featured image in wordpress blog pages as a url but I dont want to do this as part of a page load. Is this something wget can do ? If not I am assuming I need a cron job that runs a backend php script but then its kind of an API already and I feel this might be possible without a public url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
include_once('simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');

//set up curl
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$curl_html = curl_exec($ch); //use curl to get data from example.com

//use simplehtmldom to parse the site into a dom-like object
$html = str_get_html($curl_html);

echo $html;
?>
```

Here is good example & solution refer this 
[link1](http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/PHP_HTML_DOM_parser/PHPHTMLDOMParser.cc_09-07-2011.php3)
[link2](http://davidwalsh.name/php-notifications)
[link3](http://davidnash.com.au/use-curl-and-php-simple-html-dom-parser-to-inject-wordpress-into-another-page/)